# Why Coinbase API doesn't return the sell price for XRP?

Tags: coinbase-api

For various cryptocurrencies, the API returns a valid response with a sell price or spot price. Just like in this example:

```
❯ curl 'https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/XLM-EUR/sell'
{"data":{"base":"XLM","currency":"EUR","amount":"0.32"}}
```

But for XRP, it returns an error. Why? 'm guessing that it may be related to the fact that Coinbase has suspended buying XRP, but selling it is still possible so getting the rate may be required.

```
❯ curl 'https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/XRP-EUR/sell'
{"errors":[{"id":"not_found","message":"Invalid base currency"}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem using the wallet client with the code below.

```
coinbase.wallet.client.Client(
    my_key, my_secret, api_version=my_version,
).get_spot_price(currency_pair='XRP-USD')
```

It would be great to see this resolved.